# AWS CDK: how to target API Gateway API from Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an existing domain name registered with AWS Route53 and I have set up a custom domain name in API Gateway. In the console i can configure things such that xxxxxx.zenxxxxxxfoundry.com from the outside, actually reaches the API Gateway API and then on through to my Lambda functions.

Now I want to achieve this with AWS CDK.

I have tried the following:

```js
    const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneId(this, 'ZenithWebFoundryZone', 'ZXXXXXX04V8134');
    new route53.AliasRecord(this, 'BlogAPIRecord', {
      zone: zone,
      recordName: 'xxxxxx.zenxxxxxxfoundry.com',
      target: {
        bind: (): route53.AliasRecordTargetProps => ({
          dnsName: 'd-xxxxxxy00g.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
          hostedZoneId: 'ZXXXXXX04V8134'
        })
      }
    });
```

which builds ok `npm run build` but when I run `cdk synth` I get the rather obtuse error:

```
$ cdk synth
HostedZone.fromHostedZoneId doesn't support "zoneName"
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

Switching on `--trace` didn't really help much: the additional info:

```
Error: Subprocess exited with error 1
    at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (/Users/mikecoxon/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cxapp/exec.ts:108:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
```

I have looked through the whole stack script and there is no reference to `zoneName` anywhere. Does anyone know where this error comes from?

Comment: `ZenithWebFoundryZone` is a zone name you are passing in `fromHostedZoneId` method? The documentation says that the 2nd parameter to `fromHostedZoneId` is `id` but doesn't explain id of what.

Comment: No it's actually the third parameter. "id" seems **always** to be the second parameter for these factory methods, and most of the examples seem to present that as a kind of handle for the construct being made. However, most of the examples don't actually use the handle, so I assume it has some application in the resulting Cloud Formation Template.

Comment: I referred to this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.HostedZone.html and it is from AWS.... as per that the third parameter is `hostedZoneId`.... but there is no explanation about `id` parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `aws-cdk` v1 should be able to do the following:

```ts
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'ZenithWebFoundryZone', {
  hostedZoneId: 'ZXXXXXX04V8134',
  zoneName: 'zenxxxxxxfoundry.com' // your zone name here
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'BlogAPIRecord', {
  zone,
  recordName: 'xxxxxx.zenxxxxxxfoundry.com',
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias({
    bind() {
      return {
        dnsName: 'd-xxxxxxy00g.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com', // Specify the applicable domain name for your API.,
        hostedZoneId: 'XXXX', // Specify the hosted zone ID for your API.
      };
    },
  }),
});
```

If your API is in the same stack/code base you can get the `dnsName` and `hostedZoneId` from it (it's a CF attribute).

Otherwise refer to [`DNSName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html#cfn-route53-aliastarget-dnshostname) and [`HostedZoneId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html#cfn-route53-aliastarget-hostedzoneid) in the [AWS::Route53::RecordSet AliasTarget documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html).

**Note**:  the `hostedZoneId` for your alias record is **not** the same as the hosted zone id of your own zone.

Comment: I'm on the verge of confirming your suggestion, however, I seem to be [beset with this issue now](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/2713), and can't perform `cdk synth` for the moment.

Comment: confirmed this works - thank you so much. I had a lot of issues cleanly updating to 0.34.0 through npm.

Comment: I'm seeing `AddressRecordTarget` deprecated in my editor. I don't know yet what to replace it with - I will update here if I can.

Comment: @halfer use `RecordTarget`, updated the answer.

Comment: Lovely, thanks for the edit. I may have [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616710/how-can-i-set-up-my-hostedzone-so-that-it-delegates-to-a-parent-dns-record-in-an) before getting to that though - I am wanting to create a HostedZone in CDK where I need to delegate the DNS to another AWS account. You don't happen to know how to assume a role set up in a remote account, do you? All the examples I find is using roles to do something in deployed objects, rather than roles to do the deployment itself.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue using cdk 1.36.1 and managed to solve it using a new Custom Domain Name in ApiGateway, together withBasePath Mapping and then adding a CName record in an existing hosted zone on route53 pointing to the new custom domain:

```js
import {BasePathMapping, DomainName, EndpointType, LambdaRestApi} from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway';
import {Certificate} from '@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager';
import {HostedZone, CnameRecord} from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53'

// First create a custom domain:
const customDomain = new DomainName(this, 'customDomain', {
      domainName: 'api.xxxxxxx.com',
      certificate: Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'ACM_Certificate', ACM_CERTIFICATE_ARN),
      endpointType: EndpointType.EDGE
});

// create a new ApiGateway instance and associate a lambda function with it:
const api = new LambdaRestApi(this, 'MainGatewayEndpoint', {
      handler: toyFunction,
});

// Associate the Custom domain that we created with new APIGateway using BasePathMapping:
new BasePathMapping(this, 'CustomBasePathMapping', {
      domainName: custom,
      restApi: api
});

// Get a reference to AN EXISTING hosted zone using the HOSTED_ZONE_ID. You can get this from route53
const hostedZone = HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'HostedZone', {
      hostedZoneId: PROD_HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
      zoneName: 'xxxxxxx.com'
});

// Finally, add a CName record in the hosted zone with a value of the new custom domain that was created above:
new CnameRecord(this, 'ApiGatewayRecordSet', {
      zone: hostedZone,
      recordName: 'api',
      domainName: customDomain.domainNameAliasDomainName
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In AWS CDK 0.36.1 you can use the @aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets package to create aliases.

```
import { HostedZone, RecordSet, RecordType, RecordTarget } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53'
import { ApiGatewayDomain } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets'
import { Certificate } from '@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager'

// ...

  const customDomain = new apigateway.DomainName(this, 'CustomDomain', {
    domainName: props.apiDomain,
    certificate: Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'Certificate', props.certificateArn),
    endpointType: apigateway.EndpointType.EDGE,
  })

  const hostedZone = HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'HostedZone', {
    hostedZoneId: props.hostedZoneId,
    zoneName: props.hostedZoneName,
  })

  new RecordSet(this, 'ApiRecordSetA', {
    zone: hostedZone,
    recordType: RecordType.A,
    recordName: 'api',
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGatewayDomain(customDomain))
  })

  new RecordSet(this, 'ApiRecordSetAAAA', {
    zone: hostedZone,
    recordType: RecordType.AAAA,
    recordName: 'api',
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGatewayDomain(customDomain))
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working but was caught out with the Hosted Zone name requiring the '.' at the end of it.

This is for EXISTING hosted zones that have been created manually and need to be looked up to add alias records through CDK.

```
const hostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'HostedZone', {
  hostedZoneId: config.apiHostedZoneId,
  name: `${config.apiDomainName}.`,
});

new route53.RecordSet(this, 'ApiRecordSetA', {
  zone: hostedZone,
  recordType: route53.RecordType.A,
  recordName: config.apiDomainName,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53Targets.ApiGatewayDomain(apiDomain))
});

new route53.RecordSet(this, 'ApiRecordSetAAAA', {
  zone: hostedZone,
  recordType: route53.RecordType.AAAA,
  recordName: config.apiDomainName,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53Targets.ApiGatewayDomain(apiDomain))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with the following:

```js
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneId(this, 'MyZone', 'ZXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

I have a zone in Route53 similar to below:

```
Domain Name:    example.com.
Type:           Public Hosted Zone
Hosted Zone ID: ZXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I changed to the following and it worked (CDK 0.34.0):

```js
const zone = new route53.HostedZoneProvider(this,  {
  domainName: 'example.com',
}).findAndImport(this, 'MyZone');
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, I was just afraid to try it, because I thought it might clobber my current hosted zone, which is set up and working. Maybe I should shut my eyes and try it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Documentation for Hosted Zones - specifically the methods fromHostedZoneID and fromHostedZoneAttributes:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.HostedZone.html#static-fromwbrhostedwbrzonewbrattributesscope-id-attrs

it specifically mentions that "Hosted zone name becomes unavailable through this query"

the HostedZone object returned by fromHostedZoneID does not have an attribute for zoneName and so can't be used with  route53.AliasRecord - you have to use fromHostedZoneAttributes. in order to retrieve the information setting the A record requires for cdk.

Of note: if you are assigning a domain in the declaration of your API, then use (in python cause that's what I have handy, sorry)

```
route53.ARecord(
        self, "DomainAliasLogicalID",
        zone=route53_host_zone,
        target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(route53_targets.ApiGateway(your_api_object)),
        record_name=your_domain_name
    )
```

If your setting up your own domain name object (not part of the API Gateway use route53_targets.ApiGatewayDomain(your_domain_object)