# How can I set up my HostedZone so that it delegates to a parent DNS record in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

### Introduction

I have some TypeScript code that uses CDK to create an API Gateway and a Lambda. It works and deploys to a standard AWS URL. So far so good.

I now need to transfer the API Gateway so that it operates on a custom domain, so that it can set a cookie in a web app. This is proving far harder, and I suspect I am having difficulty because I am new to TypeScript, AWS, and CDK all at the same time. There are a number of documentation resources on the web, but most would require me to rewrite the precious little working code I have, which I am reluctant to do.

I have created a certificate manually, because that requires validation and thus it does not make sense to create it in code. Other than that I want all other resources to be created by CDK code in a Stack. In my view, it defeats the purpose of CDK if I have to configure things manually.

### Problem

The below code deploys everything I need to `gatekeeper.d.aws.example.com` - a HostedZone, an ARecord, a LambdaRestApi and a Function (lambda). However it does not work because the NS records newly assigned to `gatekeeper.d.aws.example.com` do not match the ones in the parent `d.aws.example.com`.

I think this means that although `d.aws.example.com` is "known", the `gateway` subdomain cannot delegate to it.

Here is my working code:

```
// Create the lambda resource
const referrerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'EisReferrerLambda', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    handler: 'index.handler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../../src/lambda')),
    environment: env
});

// Set up the domain name on which the API should appear
const domainName = 'gatekeeper.d.aws.example.com';

// TODO need to fetch it with an env var? Or read from environment?
const certificateArn = 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxx:certificate/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy';

const certificate = acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'SslCertificate', certificateArn);

const hostedZone = new route53.HostedZone(this, 'EisReferrerHostedZone', {
    zoneName: domainName
});

// Add an A record
new route53.ARecord(this, 'DnsRecord', {
    zone: hostedZone,
    target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.ApiGateway(apiGateway)),
});

// I think I need a DomainNameOptions object
const dno : DomainNameOptions = { certificate, domainName };

// Create the APIG resource
// See https://intro-to-cdk.workshop.aws/the-workshop/4-create-apigateway.html
const apiGateway = new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "EisReferrerApi", {
    handler: referrerLambda,
    // proxy = on means that the lambda handles all requests to the APIG,
    // instead of just explicit resource endpoints
    proxy: false,
    // deploy = on means that we get a default stage of "prod", I don't want
    // that - I'm creating a custom Deployment anyway
    deploy: false,
    // Point to a domain name options object
    domainName: dno
});

// Create an endpoint in the APIG
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html#defining-apis
const items = apiGateway.root.addResource('gatekeeper');
items.addMethod('GET');  // GET /default/gatekeeper

// The deployment resource is just needed by the Stage system
const deployment = new apigw.Deployment(
    this,
    'EisReferrerDeployment',
    { api: apiGateway }
);

// Create a Stage (this affects the first component in the path
const stageName = 'default';
apiGateway.deploymentStage = new apigw.Stage(
    this,
    stageName,
    { deployment, stageName }
);
```

### Question

As you can see from the code, I've found how to create an A record, but creating/modifying NS records seems harder. For a start, there does not seem to be an NSRecord class, at least based on exploring the class structure from my IDE autocomplete.

A rudimentary solution would allow me to create NS records with the fixed values that are set up elsewhere (in the AWS account that "owns" the domain). A better solution would be to read what those records are, and then use them.

### Update

To see if my thinking is on the right track, I have run this deployment code, and manually modified the automatically assigned NS records in the HostedZone to match the records in the parent (in the other account). I think I have to wait for this change to seep into the DNS system, and I will update with the result.

### Update 2

My manual adjustment did not work. I have therefore found a [new thing to try](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-route53-readme.html#adding-records) (see "To add a NS record to a HostedZone in different account"):

```
// Commented out from earlier code
// const hostedZone = new route53.HostedZone(this, 'EisReferrerHostedZone', {
//     zoneName: domainName
// });

// In the account containing the HostedZone
const parentZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'HostedZone', {
    zoneName: 'd.aws.example.com',
    crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal: new iam.AccountPrincipal('12345678012')
});

// In this account
const subZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'SubZone', {
    zoneName: domainName
});

new route53.CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord(this, 'delegate', {
    delegatedZone: subZone,
    parentHostedZoneId: parentZone.hostedZoneId,
    delegationRole: parentZone.crossAccountDelegationRole
});
```

This sounds exactly what I need, but I fear the AWS documentation is out of date here - `crossAccountDelegationRole` is rendered in red in my IDE, and it crashes due to being undefined when `cdk diff` is run.

### Update 3

I am assuming the property mentioned above is a typo or a reference to an outdated version of the library. I am now doing this:

```
new route53.CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord(this, 'delegate', {
    delegatedZone: subZone,
    parentHostedZoneId: parentZone.hostedZoneId,
    delegationRole: parentZone.crossAccountZoneDelegationRole
});
```

This feel tantalisingly close, but it crashes:

> Failed to create resource. AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/CustomCrossAccountZoneDelegationC-xxx is not authorized to
> perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::yyyyyyyyyyyy:role/HostedZoneCrossAccountZoneDelegat-yyy

I wonder if I need to declare the IAM creds for the other account? I do have them.

I am not sure why permissions are needed, anyway - could it not just read the NS records in the other account and copy them to the local account? The DNS in the other account is public anyway.

I am willing to research fixing the IAM error, but this doesn't half feel like shooting in the dark. I might spend another two hours inching towards solving that sub-problem, only to find that the whole thing will fail for another reason.

### Update 4

I have created a "Role" in the remote account to give "AmazonRoute53FullAccess" perms to the account that I am targetting for CDK deployment. However I still get the AccessDenied error. I wonder if I need to explicitly invoke that remote role in some fashion; how can I do that?

Comment: Further thoughts, to tempt a reader into answering. Perhaps I could set up a IAM role manually from one account to another? I have never done this before, but perhaps there is a way of invoking that policy from code without having to handle the second set of creds, that would be good.

Comment: It is not ideal for me to have to set up more manual things, as this is starting to defeat the point of using CDK (and CDK is a requirement of the project). Nevertheless I will do it if that gets it working.

Comment: Full disclosure, I have cross-posted this to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1057000/how-can-i-set-up-my-hostedzone-so-that-it-delegates-to-a-parent-dns-record-in-an). I hesitated to post there, as I wonder if there is too much code to make it purely an infra question. Plus, to my surprise, they don't have a CDK tag at all.

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't create the `gatekeeper` record in the `d.aws.example.com` hosted zone?

Comment: @jogold: let me clarify my terms so that I don't create confusion. The CDK code is targetting an AWS account that I call the "local" account (this account is the account for which I have created secret tokens to put in `aws configure`). The root subdomain `d.aws.example.com` is owned by another AWS account, which I will call the "remote" account. I have created a cert in the local account manually (since it needed manual validation steps).

Comment: So when I create `gatekeeper.d.aws.example.com` programmatically in the local account, it gets four random NS records automatically, but my understanding is that nothing connects it to the parent `d.aws.example.com`. Thus `gatekeeper...` remains unresolvable.

Comment: I believe to fix this, I need to copy the NS records that are programmatically created in the local account into the parent in the remote account, in order for the DNS of the new subdomain `gatekeeper...` to be "delegated". I accept this assumption may be wrong.

Comment: So, I think you are asking why I don't create "gatekeeper" locally. In fact, I think that is what my code is trying to do, but it fails on the `CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord` operation. This sounds to my ears exactly what I want, but I could be entirely wrong. I just want my subdomain to point to an API Gateway, and I want to create the subdomain programmatically.

Comment: If I can create a subdomain in the local account without needing to do this explicit remote account operation, I am all ears. I would have thought the local account would not be regarded as an authoritative DNS server for the domain (since the NS records are random + different to the parent).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Was trying to do the same thing today & your post got me 90% of the way there, thanks! I ended up getting it to work with a different IAM principal (Organization) which was ok for my use case.

The crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal gives access to accounts hosting *subzones*, to access your *root zone* and write delegation (NS) records for the subzones.

For my use case, all the accounts resided within the same organization, so I created my root zone like this ->

```
const rootZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'rootZone', {
      zoneName: `root.zone`,
      crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal: new iam.OrganizationPrincipal('o-####')
    });
```

This sets up an IAM role with the following policy;

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/#####",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following trust policy;

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-####"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which effectively allows anyone with that OrgID to write records in the root zone.

---

In my subzones, I run with this;

```
const subZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'SubZone', {
      zoneName: 'sub.root.zone'
    });

const delegationRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'delegationRole', 'arn:aws:iam::###:role/###')

    new route53.CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord(this, 'delegate', {
      delegatedZone: subZone,
      parentHostedZoneId: '###',
      delegationRole: delegationRole
    });
```

This ended up creating the delegation records in the root zone, for my subzone. If the organization principal doesn't fit your use case and you still need to grant multiple accounts that authority, try the composite principal https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.CompositePrincipal.html

---

Also wanted to address the concerns raised in the other answer around it being an anti-pattern & cross-account CDK being hard. This isn't really cross account CDK. This is utilizing a pattern provided by AWS (specifically spinning up a lambda to execute the provisioning of subzone records in a root zone).

Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am pleased my question helped - there was very little on this topic on Stack Overflow when I did my research. From what you are saying (I created my root zone like this, In my subzones I run with this) it sounds like you are running these two pieces of CDK code separately, one per account. If so, that accords with the advice I put in my answer - that doing this all from one account (and reaching from one into the other) is tricky.

Comment: It may just be that I am new to CDK, but this theme feels like being chucked in the deep end! `:=)`

Comment: (FWIW, my project was quite delayed by how long it took to write the CDK, so I moved the main body of the work into the same account as the parent domain, which thus meant I could skip over this problem. I am therefore accepting your answer, as it does not avoid the question in the way mine did!)

Comment: Definitely the deep end!

I do run the code in two separate accounts, primarily because I assumed the underlying execution engine being cloudformation, is pretty restricted to account and region. It's painful when coming from a terraform background, that's for sure. Just chuck in a new provider and away you go...

Hopefully this answer helps others too, thanks!

Comment: Here is the link to the CDK v2 version https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord.html#example

But, thanks so much for this question and answer. Got me where I needed to go.

Answer (score 2):

I used the accepted answer to create this GitHub project which implements a proof-of-concept:

- https://github.com/adamcbuckley/CdkCloudfrontUsingDnsFromAnotherAccount

> This sample project demonstrates how to use the AWS CDK serve static web content using a Cloudfront distribution. The Cloudfront distribution is given a domain name and an HTTPS certificate, even though the Route 53 hosted zone is owned by a different AWS Account (the parent account).

Answer (score 1):

I have consulted two AWS experts, and they do not favour cross-account operations. One said:

> This is an anti-pattern, since it requires permissions to remain even after the stack is deployed. What happens if a cross-account operation has to roll back and that permission is revoked? It would result in the app being stuck in a middle/undefined state (the local part is rolled back, but the remote part cannot be rolled back due to an access violation).

The other advised:

> Cross-account CDK is hard.
>
> It is much better to split your stacks into two or more operations, so you can run them independently. This applies nicely to "one off" operations like DNS delegation - realistically you are not going to change the zone delegation for your Stack unless you destroy it, which you are not going to do until you actually don't need it. Thus, there is no reason for the zone information to change for the lifetime of the system.
>
> This also works well where you have an app and a database, and you want the ability to take down your app without destroying the data.

So, this is an answer in the sense that some folks will say "don't do it". However, it looks like AWS has the ability to do it, so answers in that direction are still welcome.